# Best Practices to manage,build,deploy both 32 bit and 64 bit Versions of a Desktop C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, version-control, msbuild, build-automation

Is there any Best Practices document or manual from Microsoft which outlines the best practices to manage the development, build and deployment of both 32 version and 64 bit version of a C# Windows Application.

I have been searching all over, and found information in bits and pieces individually on some of these aspects, but not a complete guide yet.

The typical problem we are facing here is that we have both 32 bit and 64 bit dev machines and we build and test 32 bit version of the codes in 32 bit machines and 64 bit on 64 Bit machines. We can build 32 bit in 64 bit machines also, but we have kept it this way as testing becomes easier if everything of 32 bit is done on 32 and we get less issues after shipping code.

The main issue is to manage the 64 bit libs and 32 bit libs, and  its quite a hassle. The devs need to remove all the 32 bit libs and add references to 64 bit libs and then make a build and do vice versa on 32 bit machines.

I thought to write a build script but it wont also solve the issue of manually changing the reference libs, it will only tell which libs to reference while building.

I am sure every developer is facing this issue and there must be some better way out than how we are doing it right now.

Could anyone point out how to better manage this and make the process more automated and efficient?

Comment: Every Platform target (x86 and x64) should have a different output directory where the specific libraries are kept separated

Comment: If you program does not need to call any DLL written in native code (such as C/C++), AnyCPU is the best choice.

Comment: I am using certain libs like sqlite, chilkat etc, which need 64 bit binaries and 32 bit binaries respectively, so AnyCPU is not an option.